# Custom inspector enum reset on play

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a custom editor script that has an enum to define whether or not the application should launch into a setup or live mode. If I set the enum to no, when I hit play, the application works correctly with the no selection, but then the enum reverts back to the yes state, and when I exit play mode, the enum is back in the yes state, and not the state that was selected before play. Here is my script.

```cs
[CustomEditor(typeof(MainController))]
public class MainControllerEditor : Editor
{
    public enum IsSetupEnabled
    {
        Yes,
        No
    };

    public IsSetupEnabled SetupEnabled;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        GUI.changed = false;
        var mainController = (MainController)target;

        SetupEnabled = (IsSetupEnabled)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Setup Enabled", SetupEnabled);
        if (GUI.changed)
        {
            switch (SetupEnabled)
            {
                case IsSetupEnabled.Yes:
                    mainController.SetupEnabled(true);
                    break;
                case IsSetupEnabled.No:
                    mainController.SetupEnabled(false);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Validate Configuration"))
        {
            mainController.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried marking the enum as Serializable as well as marking mainController as dirty in Gui.Changed when I found solutions to this problem that other people were having, but it did not seem to do anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your SetupEnabled variable to MainController from MainControllerEditor.

Then it will be serialized, saved and loaded by the built-in serialization.

```
public enum IsSetupEnabled
{
    Yes,
    No
};

public IsSetupEnabled SetupEnabled;
```

To make your variable not show up in the inspector(but be serialized) and not execute in runtime:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
public enum IsSetupEnabled
{
    Yes,
    No
};

[HideInInspector]
public IsSetupEnabled SetupEnabled;
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

MainControllerEditor class is not serialized, there is no place for that. So state of

`public IsSetupEnabled SetupEnabled;`

is reset every time new instance of MainControllerEditor is created.
If you want to store some data you need to do it in class MainController (and it will be serialized to prefab or saved in Scene) or use Playerprefs/EditorPrefs

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    DrawDefaultInspector();
    GUI.changed = false;
    var mainController = (MainController)target;
    mainController.SetupEnabled=GUILayout.Toggle(mainController.SetupEnabled);
}
```